# Can we check the hive deleted table history or detailed information around it?

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, external-tables, hive-table

I have came across one scenario where someone dropped/deleted hive table from production environment by mistake.

**How can I track the history and get the details i.e.(who has deleted and when it got deleted).**

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this link https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/78676/is-there-a-way-to-find-the-person-who-deleted-a-di.html

Here if ambari is installed in your cluster, you can see who deleted the directory. Hive stores data in the HDFS so, you must have Location of hive table before searching the same.